# Working out the average energy for a single-ion heat engine at each stage

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

I am currently writing a report based on the Single-Ion Heat Engine at Maximum Power by O. Abah et al and I am struggling to understand how they managed to derive the expressions for the average energy at each stage of the quantum Otto cycle.

[image]

The paper states that it solves the Schrodinger equation and then uses the Gaussian wavefunction ansatz in order to derive it but the steps are unclear.

Answer (score 0):

At points A and C, the state of the oscillator is a Gibbs (also sometimes simply called "thermal") state:
$$\rho_{A,C} = \frac{1}{Z_{A,C}} e^{-\beta_{A,C} H_{A,C}}.$$
These states are established as a result of thermalization with corresponding baths. Thus, in A and C, the averages are simply thermal averages.

As regards $\langle H \rangle_B$, it is calculated not on a thermal state — the state of the system at point B is whatever results from evolving $\rho_A$ under the time-dependent quadratic Hamiltonian
$$H(t) = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{m \omega(t)^2 x^2}{2},$$
where
$$\omega(t_{\mathrm{initial}}) = \omega_1 \quad \mathrm{and} \quad \omega(t_{\mathrm{final}}) = \omega_2.$$
When $t_{\mathrm{final}} - t_{\mathrm{initial}} \to \infty$, the evolution is adiabatic, and $Q_1^* = 1$; in general, it is $\geq 1$. Note that the expression "Gaussian ansatz" can be misleading here, as the state *does remain exactly Gaussian* throughout the whole cycle as the Hamiltonian of the system stays quadratic.

The same logic of course goes with $\langle H \rangle_D$.